# LINQ Join sub-select

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 in memory lists and I want to join on a sub select. It doesn't appear doable with a straight `LINQ` `Join` construct. Any suggestions?

```
Authors = {
    { Name = "Tom", Ref = { 1, 2, 3 } },
    { Name = "Dick", Ref = { 3, 4, 5 } },
    { Name = "Harry", Ref = { 1, 5 } }
}

Refs = {
    { ID = 1, Location = "Home" },
    { ID = 2, Location = "Work" },
    { ID = 3, Location = "School" },
    { ID = 4, Location = "Camping" },
    { ID = 5, Location = "Travel" }
}

Result = {
    { Name = "Tom", Locations = { "Home", "Work", "School" } },
    { Name = "Dick", Locations = { "School", "Camping", "Travel" } },
    { Name = "Harry", Locations = { "Home", "Travel" } }
}
```

Comment: Given that you wanted to join two lists, and you knew you wanted to use LINQ, why did you not start out by say looking at the documentation for the `Join` method.  You clearly already knew enough to find it.

Comment: Correct, you would end up actually using a `GroupJoin`, which does *exactly* what you want, and a trivial amount of research into the subject would have lead you there.

Comment: This is a community that values high quality questions; it values people doing research and spending effort trying to solve their own problems before asking others for help.  It's a community that has standards, and enforces them enthusiastically.  I'm honestly shocked that, given you're contributions to it, you would have figured that out by now.  But better late than never.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Authors.Select(
    i=>new {Name = i.Name, 
            Locations = Refs.Where(
                          j=>i.Ref.Contains(j.ID)).Select(j=>j.Location)});
```

Comment: This won't scale nearly as effectively as a proper join as you're performing a linear search through one list for each item in the other.

Comment: Yes. I assumed it is going to be used for small datasets.

Answer (score 2):

You can **avoid** `join on sub-select` in the following way:

```
Authors.Select(author => new {
                                Name = author.Name, 
                                Locations = author.Ref.Select(id => Refs.Single(x => x.ID == id).Location)
                            }
              );
```

---

### EDIT

To optimize the performance of `sub-select`, I would rather make a dictionary of `Refs` and then use it directly in the `sub-select` like below:

```
var dictRefs = Refs.ToDictionary(key => key.ID, value => value.Location);
var Results = Authors.Select(author => new {
                                Name = author.Name, 
                                Locations = author.Ref.Select(id => dictRefs[id])
                                           }
                            );
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create a few classes:

```
public class Author {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Ref { get; set; } 
}

public class Ref {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

public class Result {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Locations { get; set; } 

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("Name: {0}. Locations: {1}", Name, string.Join(", ", Locations));
    }
}
```

The following code will do the trick:

```
var authors = new List<Author>
    {
        new Author {Name = "Tom", Ref = new List<int> {1, 2, 3}},
        new Author {Name = "Dick", Ref = new List<int> {3, 4, 5}},
        new Author {Name = "Harry", Ref = new List<int> {1, 5}},
    };

var refs = new List<Ref>
    {
        new Ref {ID = 1, Location = "Home"},
        new Ref {ID = 2, Location = "Work"},
        new Ref {ID = 3, Location = "School"},
        new Ref {ID = 4, Location = "Camping"},
        new Ref {ID = 5, Location = "Travel"}
    };

var result = authors.Select(x => new Result
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Locations = x.Ref.Select(y => refs.FirstOrDefault(z => z.ID == y).Location).ToList()
    }).ToList();


result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

The above code will print:

> Name: Tom. Locations: Home, Work, School
>   Name: Dick. Locations: School, Camping, Travel
>   Name: Harry. Locations: Home, Travel

It will assume that all the IDs exist in `refs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from a in Authors
select new {Name = a.Name, 
           Locations = Refs.Where(r=>a.Ref.Contains(r.ID)).Select(r=>r.Location)}
```